# AWK check date if today then filter only that content

Tags: awk

I am trying to read a text file that has the following data:

```
LNAME FNAME MNAME MAJOR DATE
Smith Jane Chem  Date:[somedate]
Doe Joanne Victoria ENG Date:[today]
```

In this example [somedate] means any date that is not today, [today] means today's date. The idea is that I use awk to filter out all the students that register today. The Date format would look like this: 2022-06-21.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If it doesn't have to be awk, grep is a better choice: `grep -v $(date +'%F') filename`

Comment: @MDeBusk: why is grep a better choice?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I think it's a simpler command line and easier to remember. If I wanted to put it in a script, I'd use awk.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker but I have a question about `filter` and `filter out` are both the same or they are opposite?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon "To filter" and "to filter out" are equivalent in English. "The "out" is redundant because filtering implies removing something from something.

Comment: If you have control over the file format, you might consider removing the space from the beginning of the second and third fields. It can make filtering a little easier.

Comment: @MDeBusk thanks! I've seen that the answers of this question give different results. In your answer you get all the records which don't match with the current date while the Arkadiusz's answer displays the records which match with the current date

Comment: @EdgarMagallon If I were to ask for only those students who registered today, I'd ask that they be filtered FOR, not OUT. I'm wondering if I've misunderstood the intend of the questioner.

Comment: I fear I may have misunderstood what you wanted. Do you want the output to contain all students who registered today and none other, or all students who registered on any date but today?

Comment: @MDeBusk thank you very much!! I've learned something new :D. By the way , is it equivalent to say `filter by` and `filter for`?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I think "filter by" denotes something different than "filter for," but that may be idiomatic to me. I'd say "filter by the contents of the third field" (or some variable or type) and "filter for today's date", that is to say, something specific.

Comment: @MDeBusk nicee, thanks again!!

Comment: @EdgarMagallon There are several articles that could be applied after the work filter.  The general goal of a filter is to differentiate some particular attribute of what is being filtered. Thinking of rocks, for example, you can filter **by** size, or filter **by** color, or filter **by** weight. Then, after applying some filter the requested output could be to accept that which is being filtered (or to filter **in**) or could be to reject what is being filtered (or to filter **out**).

Comment: In this question, the title `filter only that content` gets clarified in the question text with `filter **out** all the students that register today`. It doesn't seem reasonable to understand that description to `filter in` today's students.

Comment: @QuartzCristal thank you very much!! All these comments are very useful for me. I really was wrong  and I thought that MDeBusk's answer was incorrect. Everything now is clear :). Thank you both!

Comment: With all dates (including today) in yyyy-mm-dd format, sort -nrk5 will get you all you need.

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -v "Date:$(date +%F)\$" < file
```

Would return the lines that don't end in `Date:` followed by the current date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

If using `zsh`, you can do that without having to invoke `date` with:

```
grep -v Date:${(%):-%D{%F}}$ < file
```

The GNU implementation of `awk` can also get the current date by itself:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {search = strftime("Date:%F")}
      $NF != search' < file
```

Would return the lines whose last blank delimited field is not `Date:[today]`.

Change to:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {search = strftime("Date:%F")}
      NR == 1 || $NF != search' < file
```

To also print the header.

On systems where `awk` is not the GNU `awk`, you can do:

```
awk -v search="$(date +Date:%F)" '
  NR == 1 || $NF != search' < file
```

Or:

```
awk 'BEGIN {"date +Date:%F" | getline search}
     NR == 1 || $NF != search' < file
```

(though that one runs an extra shell invocation to interpret that `date +Date:%F` shell code; that approach would only be useful in a `#! /usr/bin/awk -f` script).

If the input can be parsed as some sort of csv with space as separator, you could also use csvkit's `csvgrep`:

```
<file csvgrep -d ' ' -c DATE -r "$(date +'^Date:%F$')"
```

Here matching on the `DATE` field.

The output is comma-separated-value though. You can change the delimiter back to space instead of comma by piping to `csvformat -D ' '`.

Comment: Why are you escaping the `$`? What grep/shell combination will choke on `grep "...$"`? I am guessing there is a condition where the `$"` is treated as a variable by the shell?

Comment: @terdon, IIRC, POSIX allows `$"` to be handled as a special parameter, so `"whatever$"` is unspecified per POSIX, while `"whatever\$"` is fully specified (to expand to `whatever$`). In practice though, I don't know of any shell where the backslash is necessary (note that `ksh93` and `bash` have a `$"..."` form of quote that makes use of the fact that POSIX leaves `$"` unspecified). More generally, you want to escape `$` so it be taken literally, outside of single quotes.

Comment: First off thank you! I had to update the example.

Comment: Thank you for helping, but I only have access to awk not gawk.

Comment: @user9980782, on many systems including most GNU ones `awk` is actually `gawk`. See edit for how to do it with other `awk` implementations.

Comment: Regarding "The GNU implementation of awk can also get the current date by itself:": Does gawk have to get the current date for each line, or is it done once? I'm wondering if there's a cost in CPU cycles to doing it this way. For a file with two lines it's no problem, but for many hundreds of records it might be expensive.

Comment: @MDeBusk, there's a clue in "BEGIN"

Comment: little typo in the gawk exemple's description: "Would return the lines whose last blank delimited field is" should be "isn't" at the end

Comment: Thanks @OlivierDulac, the initial version of the answer filtered in instead of out, and it looks like I missed some bits when reversing. Fixed now.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'd missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please indicate where is a quoted `$` (inside double quotes) required to also have an escape `\$` in the POSIX spec? Perhaps you are getting confused with an unquoted `$"` that does start a

Comment: @QuartzCristal, see XCU 2.6.2. *Otherwise, the parameter is a single-character symbol, and behavior is unspecified if that character is neither a digit nor one of the special parameters*

Comment: But: How could it be a "single character symbol" if there is nothing following the `$`. Note that the trailing `"` is consumed by the "enclosed in double quotes" part. In other words, a double quoted string starts with an unquoted "double quote" until the next, also unquoted, "double quote". What is left is only a `$` which has no following character to interpret. @StéphaneChazelas

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```bash
awk -F'[ :]' -v dt="$(date +'%F')" '$NF != dt' filename
```

- `-F'[ :]'` tells awk to use either the space or the colon as the field separator
- `-v` tells awk to use the following as a variable
- `dt="$(date +'%F')"` sets `dt` to the current date in YYYY-MM-DD format
- `'$NF != dt'` says "ignore this line if the last field equals the current date"

Comment: @user9980782 Your alteration to the file format in your question is so severe that most of the answers don't work any longer. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks, when I run this I get:

Smith Jane Chem  Date:[somedate]
Doe Joanne Victoria ENG Date:[today]
[blank line]


It doesn't filter just prints all the data

Comment: @user9980782 :  is the line in the log files always :  `...... yyyy-mm-dd` ?  (with a space before yyyy) ? which is what this answer is looking for? or if your file looks different please show a true exemple

Comment: @user9980782 I copied and pasted your example data file, replaced `[somedate]` with `2022-09-` and an arbitrary two-digit number < 30, and replaced `[today]` with the output of `$date +'%F'`. It worked for me. I'm running GNU awk 5.1.0.

Answer (score 3):

Get current date with with [command
substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)
and compare $NF:

```
awk -F, -v date="$(date +%F)" '$NF == date' FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, to filter the last field in AWK, you should use `$NF == "text"` or, to make it even more general: `$NF == value` where value is a variable with the appropriate content. That could be applied to any field by changing `$NF` to `$3`, for example (to filter on column `3`). That (the `==`) would `filter in` (accept) all students that registered today. To reject them, you can use `$NF != value` or `!($NF == value)` both provide the same logical result.

The value to match could be `[today]` or `Date:[today]` or `Date:2022-06-21` or anything that is required. Just make the content of the variable `value` exactly equal to what you need and this awk command will "filter out" lines with that value. Assuming the field separator is a tab:

```
awk -v value="Date:[2022-06-21]" '$NF != value' infile
```

Add a `-F","` if the field delimiter is a comma.

To get today's date you can use the shell if using bash (4.3+) or ksh (93):

```
printf -v value 'Date:[%(%F)T]'
awk -v value="$value" '$NF != value' infile
```

If the first line of the script is a header, and you want it to be printed, add:

```
printf -v value 'Date:[%(%F)T]'
awk -v value="$value" '($NF != value) || (NR==1)' infile
```

Or, in any shell:

```
value="Date:[$(date +'%F')]"
awk -v value="$value" '($NF != value) || (NR==1)' infile
```

In some versions of awk, it is possible to get the date directly:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ value = "Date:[" strftime("%F") "]" } ($NF != value) || (NR == 1)' infile
```

The `==` would make a string comparison which needs to be exact. A related test is a regex match `~` (or the negated `!~`) which could allow less strict matches (`$NF ~ /2022/` will match any string that contains a `2022` anywhere, which could probably be used to match "this year", for example).

Comment: when I run it I get: awk: calling undefined function strftime
 source line number 1

Comment: What do you mean by **it**? That you are trying the last option and it fails? Well, the line just above declares that this option works only in some versions of awk, not all. Have you tried other options from the answer? The before-last solution should work correctly in any awk.

Comment: Hi when I copy and past the command you wrote w/my file that's it.